# How to setup multiple delphi versions on jenkins node?

Tags: delphi, jenkins, delphi-2010, delphi-xe5

We have Delphi 2010 setup as described [here](http://thundaxsoftware.blogspot.de/2011/07/continuous-integration-for-your-delphi.html) and jobs are running fine.

Now we need to add Delphi XE5 to that node as well.
Problem are variables `BDS` and `BDSCOMMONDIR`.

They are set as global variables pointing to e.g. `BDS` points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0`.

For XE5, `BDS` should be have the value of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0`.

So how to setup multiple delphi versions?

Comment: I guess you need project specific environment variables: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Project-specific-environment-variables-td1458949.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using batch scripts for each build job.

Each script is able to set different environment variables. Basically I set the content of Delphi's rsvars.bat in my specific build scripts (Delphi paths, path to MSBuild depending on Delphi version etc.).

So the build script for a distinct build job contains the call to MSBuild (thus I have not set up MSBuild through Jenkins).

Could look something like this for you:

```
set BDS=C:\PathToDelphiLib
set FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
set FrameworkVersion=v3.5
set PATH=%FrameworkDir%;%BDS%\bin;%PATH%
set LANGDIR=EN
// set other variables

echo @@@ building the project
MSBuild.exe %WORKSPACE%\YourApp\YourApp.dproj "/p:Win32LibraryPath=$(BDS)\lib" /target:Build /p:config=%AConfigVariable% /p:Platform=Win32 /p:DCC_ExeOutput=%OutputDirVariable% /verbosity:quiet
```

In Jenkins then I can set up the Build using Windows Batch

```
call %WORKSPACE%\YourApp\ContinuousIntegration\DelphiXE2_Build_Release.bat
```

An advantage is that you can cascade batch scripts and keep all that logic away from Jenkins. I have also put my build scripts under version control. Everything is inside the repository and under control.

Comment: I set variables per job and configured different MSBuild environments on master and it works. I am having jenkins config file under version control. Batch files are node specific so I don't want to have them in my project, maybe in another repo.